# davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit create nodejs api endpoints. How to?

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, react-redux, endpoints

I just started to explore a bit this [reactjs-redux boilerplate](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) from davezuko which structure is fractal and I search a way to implement api endpoints to fetch data from mongodb.

What are the approaches? The way to go is to create a new route and somehow interact with Koa server?

Comment: Sorry for the OT. how are you getting on with this fractal approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading over the boilerplate docs, it looks like the author included the Koa server only to load the hot module middleware.

If you want to create your own API endpoints for mongodb, you might want to create your own to separate concerns.

From the docs:

> Server
>
> This starter kit comes packaged with an Koa server. **It's important to
>   note that the sole purpose of this server is to provide
>   webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware for hot module
>   replacement.** Using a custom Koa app in place of webpack-dev-server
>   makes it easier to extend the starter kit to include functionality
>   such as API's, universal rendering, and more -- all without bloating
>   the base boilerplate.

Comment: yepp your right I omitted this part from dicumentation